# I want to post an xml to another server

Tags: java

When i run this code it gives me error xml stating---Problem processing POST request: unsupported Content-Type text/xml. I want to send an xml using httpClient to a URL which is a web service url

```
  public class HTTPClientDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

 try
 {
     String inputXML = "<Style>0206.ard</Style><BoardCode>I-175B</BoardCode><BoardDesc>I-175 B Kraft</BoardDesc><GrainDirection>Vertical</GrainDirection><Unit>mm</Unit><PrintSide>Inside</PrintSide><Length>100</Length><Width>70</Width><Depth>45</Depth>";
     URL url = new URL( "http://egwinae002:4415/ws/wstest003" );
    // URL url = new URL( "https://dzone.com/articles/using-java-post-block-xml-web" );
     URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    // con.connect();
     // specify that we will send output and accept input
   con.setDoInput(true);
     con.setDoOutput(true);
     con.setConnectTimeout( 20000 );  // long timeout, but not infinite
     con.setReadTimeout( 20000 );
     con.setUseCaches (false);
     con.setDefaultUseCaches (false);
     // tell the web server what we are sending
     con.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "text/xml" );
     OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( con.getOutputStream() );
     writer.write( inputXML  );
     writer.flush();
     writer.close();
     // reading the response
     InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream() );
     StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
     char[] cbuf = new char[ 2048 ];
     int num;
     while ( -1 != (num=reader.read( cbuf )))
     {
         buf.append( cbuf, 0, num );
     }
     String result = buf.toString();
     System.err.println( "\nResponse from server after POST:\n" + result );

 }
 catch( Throwable t )
 {
     t.printStackTrace( System.out );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Have done modification and added some lines in your code,  hope it will work

 URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

 //Added this one to make your connection http
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) con;
// con.connect();
 // specify that we will send output and accept input
 conn .setDoInput(true);
 conn .setDoOutput(true);
 conn .setRequestProperty("accept-charset", "UTF-8");
 // tell the web server what we are sending
 conn.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "text/xml" );
// set data posting method
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

// OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( conn.getOutputStream() );

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
 writer.write( inputXML  );
 writer.close();
 // reading the response
// InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream() );
 BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
```